# Map Object in .run block breaks my unit test: ReferenceError: Can't find variable in app/scripts/app.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I set up a mock backend in my AngularJS app using ngMockE2E as I am waiting for an API. In my `.run` block I declare my various `$httpBackend.whenGET` and `$httpBackend.whenPost` methods and I have a variable to return data from these methods which is a JS Map() object... like so (not all code is here)

```
.run(function ($httpBackend) {

    var fakeData = new Map();

    fakeData.set(/*stuff goes here*/);

    $httpBackend.whenGET('/geturl').respond(function () {

        // do stuff and return parts of the Map()
    });

    $httpBackend.whenPOST('/posturl').respond(function (method, url, data) {
         // do stuff and return parts of the Map()
    });
```

Now I have set up my first unit test to test a service that uses these mock backends...

```
describe('Service: MyAppService: ', function () {

    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

    var MyAppService, $httpBackend;

    describe('MyAppService Service should be created', function () {

        beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
            MyAppService = $injector.get('MyAppService');
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            $httpBackend.when('GET', '/geturl').respond(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']);
        }));

        afterEach(function() {
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });

        it('test all is well before real tests', function () {
            expect(true).to.equal(true);
        });

    });
});
```

However with no real tests in my UnitTest I am already getting the following error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map in app/scripts/app.js`

What must I add to the Unit Test to prevent this error? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-shim, add to karma.conf.js

Comment: I have added es6-shim and added it to `frameworks: [ 'jasmine', 'es6-shim'] `in the karma.config.js and I still get the error

Comment: I have it in files section:  `files: [ 'app/bower_components/es6-shim/es6-shim.js' ]`

Comment: ah, that works!

Comment: Nice! glad to hear, for closure, will simply put as answer so not left open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PhantomJS` does not support ES5 and ES6. `Map` is ES5. RE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

You need to add es6-shim (includes es5) that implements it, see npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-shim

After installing, reference it in `karma.conf.js` in `files` section.

```
files: [ 'app/bower_components/es6-shim/es6-shim.js' ]
```